# How to widen the middle portion of OHLC chart , plotly ? The middle portion consists of Open & Close values

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash, ohlc

I was trying to make an OHLC chart using plotly and I am successfully able to do it.I am using Yfinance library to get the data and plotting an OHLC chart for certain stocks. The code that I wrote for it as.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Ohlc(x=tickerDf.index.date,  #tickerDf is the dataframe
                        open=tickerDf.Open,
                        high=tickerDf.High,
                        low=tickerDf.Low,
                        close=tickerDf.Close))

        fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False)    #Disable xticks 
        fig.update_layout(width=800,height=600,xaxis=dict(type = "category")) # hide dates with no values
        st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Chart made from this code[image]

I was wondering can we widen the middle portion of OHLC graph . Just like image below . My client is forcing me to make this possible and after spending several hours in plotly documentation I didn't find anything .I hope some of you might help me in this. Thanks in advance . If there's any alternative way to achieve this , you can share with me that as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [`go.Candlestick`](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/) instead of `go.Ohlc`. The documentation should link these components together.